# change application id in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart, gradle

I have an application called "A" . then, in the same project, I want to change the application id and replace the name with "B". now I expect both of them to get installed on one device.
how to change the application id in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are looking for Flavors, so you can install the same app with multiple flavors like the testing version and production version (A & B in your case).

You can read out this [official documentation](https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/flavors) and use [packages](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_flavorizr) to achieve flavoring for your Flutter app.